# nodejs how to wait all code done and get return value if too many async in the file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want Nodejs to save the context like this :
It's just like run Nodejs in CMD or Powershell.
First of all, I type `var temp = 10000;` and maybe after 10 minutes I type `var temp1 = temp` it can still save the value of `temp`.
but in webstorm or some other IDE how can I do it?
for example, I have an `abc.js` and `global.value =10` when I run `abc.js` it will close when the code is executed. I know some API like `express`. but if too many `async functions` in the file, it can't work well.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please explain your problem more elaborately and show what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `readline` module to wait for user input and prevent the event loop from being done with. The below code prompts fo a user input, repeats what the user types or exit if the user types "quit". I hope the logic is pretty obvious.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  prompt: 'Hello> '
});

rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', (line) => {

    if (line === 'quit')
        rl.close()
    else {
        console.log(line);
        rl.prompt();
    }

})
```